# Is diphthongising [ʌ] as [ʌɪ] novel or an accent feature?

Tags: phonetics, sound-change, dialects, accent

I have noticed some speakers diphthongising [ʌ] as [ʌɪ]. For example, in [Bea Miller’s Young Blood](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fMMNrth246k), she pronounces “young blood” as [jʌɪŋ blʌɪd] and “us” as [ʌɪs]. Has this been documented elsewhere? Is it a feature of her accent or a new development?

Comment: It's new to me.  (Adding a glide is normal in words with -ang, like "bang" or "bank".)

Comment: I don't hear it on at least the first couple of *youngs*. I'd guess the glide on *us* and *blood* to be an artefact of her singing style, maintaining the vocalization while moving the tongue forward to the forward articulation point for the consonant. You hear this sometimes in my [Southern US] dialect, which is partial to diphthongs.